# not a GROUP BY expression Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, linq

I have this query :

```
SELECT * 

FROM FTR

WHERE ROWNUM = 1

GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
```

It gives the error in the title. How can I fix this? Thanks.

EDIT :

To be more precise I'm trying to convert this LINQ query to SQL :

```
var ftr_dist = db.FTR.GroupBy(x => x.CUSTOMER_ID)
                     .Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault())
                     .ToList();
```

EDIT 2 :
In my table there are more than one rows with same `CUSTOMER_ID`, and I'm trying to take one of them (it doesn't matter which one). As a result of my query, there should be rows with unique `CUSTOMER_ID`.

Comment: `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is just broken code.  Try providing sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want a query to do.

Comment: Also, read about what `GROUP BY` is supposed to do

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited my question.

Comment: As you are requesting advice in `oracle` - could you at least explain what the above `LINQ` query is supposed to do ... otherwise you are addressing only  `LINQ` experts who also happens to  know `oralce` ...

Comment: Perhaps you could use LinqPad to see how the Linq is translated to SQL?

Comment: @Plirkee I added an explanation. Sorry, I thought the LINQ query is enough. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my table there are more than one rows with same `CUSTOMER_ID`, and I'm trying to take one of them (it doesn't matter which one). As a result of my query, there should be rows with unique `CUSTOMER_ID`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT f.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Customer_ID ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE ) AS rn
  FROM   FTR f
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

This will get one random row for each `CUSTOMER_ID`.

Comment: Is `ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` necessary? Would it make query slower?  What if I remove that? Thanks.

Comment: Just use `ORDER BY ROWNUM` or some other ordering. `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` was just put in there because you stated it "doesn't matter which" row is returned.